# Pass cookie as part of node.js request

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, request

I am using the `request` package to create my server side requests. I wrote authentication middleware that checks for a cookie/session id for all requests. Therefore, is there a way I include the user's cookie as part of the request? Here is my current code:

```
var cookie = parseCookie.parseCookie(req.headers.cookie);

request('http://localhost:3000/users/api', function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body); //this console.logs my login page since requests w/o valid cookies get redirected to login
    res.render('../views/admin');
});
```

Currently, this returns 'no cookie found' in the console. However, if I turn off my authentication middleware, the code above works as intended.

Additional info:

The cookie I want is the end user's cookie located on the browser. The end user's cookie is created by the app whenever the user logs in.

Update - solution attempt 1:

I tried this from the documentation:

```
var cookie = parseCookie.parseCookie(req.headers.cookie);
var cookieText = 'sid='+cookie;
var j = request.jar();
        var cookie = request.cookie(cookieText);
        var url = 'http://localhost:3000/users/api';
        j.setCookie(cookie, url);
        request({url: url, jar: j}, function(error, response, body) {
            request('http://localhost:3000/users/api');
        });
```

However, the console is still returning 'no cookie found'

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have top explain more about what cookie you want to send?  An end-user's cookie is stored in their browser and is uniquely associated with a particular browser and a particular domain and is sent to that domain with any requests from the browser to that domain.  Please describe what cookie you are asking about.  If the cookie belongs to a different domain than your server is on, then your server will not have access to that cookie.

Comment: @jfriend00 - i updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: What domain and port was the cookie created on?  What domain and port is your server on?

Comment: @jfriend00 the domain and port are localhost:3000, respectively. I updated my question w/ a solution i tried..

Comment: What domain and port is the server that is running the code in your question.  This is all important because the browser associates a cookie with A particular server and protects the cookie in that way.  I'm trying to figure out which server the cookie belongs to and which server you're trying to get the cookie on so you can send it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the domain and port of the server running my code.. could you let me know to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let me explain about cookies and that will probably show you why it's hard to get the cookie you want.

1. When your user's browser logs into `http://localhost:3000`, that server creates a login cookie and returns it as part of the login response.
2. When the browser receives that cookie, it saves that cookie persistently within the browser and it associates that cookie with the `http://localhost:3000` domain and port.
3. When the user again makes a request to `http://localhost:3000`, the browser sends all cookies it has previously saved for that particular domain and port with the request to the server.
4. When the server receives the request, it can examine any cookies that are sent with the request.
5. When the browser then makes a request to a different server or even the same server, but on a different port, the browser does NOT send the previously saved cookies with that request because those cookies belong to a different server and port.  The browser goes to great security lengths to send cookies only to the servers that the cookies belong to.  Since cookies often provide login access, you can clearly see why it's important that things like login credential cookies are not sent to servers they should not be sent to.

Now, on to your node.js code.  You show a block of node.js code that is trying to access the same `http://localhost:3000` server.  But, the cookies are stored in the user's browser.  Your node.js code cannot get them from the browser as the browser guards them and will only reveal them when the browser itself sends a request to `http://localhost:3000`.

---

If you do actually have the right cookie in your node.js code, then you can set it on your request like this:

```
request({url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/api', headers: {Cookie: somedataHere}}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body); //this console.logs my login page since requests w/o valid cookies get redirected to login
    res.render('../views/admin');
});
```

Relevant documentation for custom headers in the `request` module is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers).

Comment: Right, but my first line of code contains the cookie. So I technically already have the cookie, which I am trying to pass as part of my `request` function.

Comment: @user1547174 - If you actually  have the right cookie, then you can just add it as a header to the request you are sending as I now show at the end of my answer.

Comment: I found that momentarily afterwards. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 9):

Answer:

```
var cookie = parseCookie.parseCookie(req.headers.cookie);
var cookieText = 'sid='+cookie;
var options = {
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',
  headers: {
   'User-Agent': 'request'.
   'host': 'localhost:3000',
   'cookie': cookieText //this is where you set custom cookies
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
    console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: does this work? maybe add some text explaining why it's different from OP

Comment: for example, what is parseCookie?

Comment: It can be "cookie-parser" NPM module. E.g.: `router.use(require("cookie-parser")())`. Then you get this property `req.cookies` in your express.js handlers.