# Can't send an httpOnly cookie with axios or fetch

Tags: session, cookies, next.js, next-auth

I have an API route that requires a session cookie to test Authentication

> `/api/structure/[module]`

When I try to connect this route with axios like:

```
const res = await axios.get(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/structure/${params.name}`,
    { withCredentials: true }
  );
```

it doesn't work.

I am using next-auth so here's the code to get the session:

```
import {getSession} from 'next-auth/client';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const session = await getSession({ req: req });
}
```

but it returns null for the session.

***> ***The weird part is I can consume the route with the browser and it works just fine.******

I think it has something to do with the httpOnly cookie or the CURL.

**Yes I set withCredentials to true**

**And my cookie is httpOnly**

**I spent a week searching for a solution but I didn't manage to find any.
Any help Please.**

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ - Could you be more specific? Do you get any errors in the console or network tab? Are you making the `axios` request from the client or server?

Comment: what I mean by it doesn't work is when I try to get the cookies from the request I get an empty object and I am using axios in the client side

Comment: If the cookie is HttpOnly then it can't be access in the client-side.

Comment: But I want to send it to the server not get it in the client side (and I think this is something possible)

Comment: Cookies should automatically be sent from the browser. Are you sure you're successfully logged-in before making the request?

Comment: I think I resolved the issue, the problem was that I used axios inside getServerSideProps() which is a server side code but when I use in the client side it works just fine.

Comment: But is there any way to use axios in the server side code and also send the cookies stored in my browser ?

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Cookies will not automatically be sent when the request is made from the server, you need to explicitly pass them. See [Why are cookies not sent to the server via getServerSideProps in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057271/why-are-cookies-not-sent-to-the-server-via-getserversideprops-in-next-js/69058105#69058105).

Comment: Well could you please show me how to explicitly pass the cookies via axios inside a server side code

Comment: Thank you buddy I really appreciate your help ;)