# How to get cookies in getServerSideProps NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

In my User page I'm using `getServerSideProps` to get user's data.

At `console.log` number 1 you can see that `cookies` with tokens are exsists.
But at console.log number 2 `cookies` are empty

Also I did same request inside `useEffect`
And it works as I expect. And at the `console.log` number 2 cookies object contains tokens.

How to set `cookies` for `getServerSideProps` request?

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({req, res}) {
    console.log(1, req.cookies)
    
    const response = await $api.get(`/store/profile/user`, {withCredentials: true})
    
    return { props: {} }
}

const User: NextPage = ({props}) => {
    const getData = async () => {
        const response = await $api.get(`/store/profile/user`, {withCredentials: true})
    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
       getData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <LoginLayout>
            <ProfileLayout>
                <UserInfo />
            </ProfileLayout>
        </LoginLayout>
    )
}

export default User
```

```js
export default async function refresh(req, res, next) {
    try {
        console.log(2, req.cookies)
        
        const {refreshToken} = req.cookies
        const userData = await userService.refresh(refreshToken)
        res.cookie("refreshToken", userData.refreshToken, {maxAge: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true})
        return res.json(userData)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(e.status).json({message: e.message})
    }
}
```

logs for getServerSideProps request:

```js
1 {
  refreshToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InpoZW4uYWxleGVlZmZAZ21haWwuY29t',
  token:'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InpoZW4uYWxleGVlZmZAZ21haWwuY29tIiThm'
}

2 {}
```

logs for request inside useEffect:

```js
2 {
  refreshToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InpoZW4uYWxleGVlZmZAZ21haWwuY29ih',
  token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InpoZW4uYWxleGVlZmZAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWQg'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why are cookies not sent to the server via getServerSideProps in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057271/why-are-cookies-not-sent-to-the-server-via-getserversideprops-in-next-js/69058105#69058105)? When making requests from the server you need to explicitly pass the cookies to the request.

Answer (score 1):

First install cookie package using npm

```
npm install cookie
```

and then import it where you need it

```
import cookie from "cookie";
```

and the rest must be something like the following:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const mycookie = cookie.parse(
    (context.req && context.req.headers.cookie) || ""
  );

  let cookieNameData = {};
  if (mycookie.whatevercookienameis) {
    cookieNameData = mycookie.whatevercookienameis;
  }

  return { 
    props: {
      cookieNameData
    } 
  }
}
```

Hope it gives you a clear picture how to achieve it.