# Getting error invalid header token when I call Laravel API inside getStaticProps

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js

When I call this API from `useEffect` it works but when I call from `getStaticProps` I'm getting error `Invalid header token`.

How can I solve it?

```js
export async function getStaticProps(){
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shop')
    const data = await response.json()
    return {
        props:{
            users:data,
        },
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you running next.js in WSL?

Comment: @CrowRish I have a similar problem with CSRF and NextAuth and I'm running Next on WSL. How would that make a difference?

Comment: Check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/69057271/7854506

Comment: No, i am running  next js in windows 10.