# If write the URL of the web I can access the data from API, but when If I fetch in getServerSideProps it cannot get the session in Next.js (nextAuth)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, middleware, next-auth

If API is accessed as `GET` request from the browser as authenticated, you get the data.
But when you want to access the data by fetching in client-side by the function getserverside gives me the error that is not authenticated which it fact it is.

**API**

```
 export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req;
  const cookie = {
    headers: {
      cookie: req.headers["cookie"],
    },
  };

  const session = await getSession({ req: cookie });

  if (!session) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      success: false,
      message: "NOT Authorized",
    });
  }

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const jobs = await prisma.jobs.findMany({
          where: {
            userId: session.id,
          },
        });
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, jobs });
      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          success: false,
          message: error.message,
        });
      }
```

**Component**

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  console.log(req.cookies); // Logs all cookies from the request

  const cookie = {
    headers: {
      cookie: req.headers["cookie"],
    },
  };


  const session = await getSession({ req: cookie });
  console.log(session); // session is received perfectly.

  const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/company/jobs`); // ERROR NOT AUTHENTICATED

 }
```

It is a bit weird because when I try to access the data the cookie is received but when I make the request it says is not authenticated

Comment: If the `API_URL` is a different host than the one that the frontend app is running, then you have CORS issues, and you need to set `withCredentials:true` to axios config.

Comment: @IvanV. I tried it but still do not work, the API URL is the same.

The only solution I come up is by doing:

  const cookie = {
    headers: {
      cookie: req.headers["cookie"],
    },
  };

  const resul = await axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/company/jobs`, {
    cookie,
  });

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why are cookies not sent to the server via getServerSideProps in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057271/why-are-cookies-not-sent-to-the-server-via-getserversideprops-in-next-js)? You need to explicitly pass the cookies to the axios request when making the request from the server-side.

Comment: Also, if that's an internal Next.js API route then you shouldn't be making a request to it inside `getServerSideProps`. You should move the logic that's in your API route directly to `getServerSideProps` instead. See [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js).

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you should pass to `getSession` function whole original `req` in API. and whole context prop in `getServerSideProps`

https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession

Comment: You are right, but by using getSession I do not know but the session comes null.