# Sending Cookies with FETCH API as a GET request from the Frontend to the Backend

Tags: typescript, express, next.js, get, fetch-api

I'm struggling with the following problem:
I'm trying to send a cookie with a GET-Request to find out if the user is logged in or not. The cookie has been successfully sent to my browser and I can therefore view it in my developer tools. Making a request through the URL-Bar to the API works and I get the correct response of

```
{loggedIn : true}
```

But if I call the url programatically through

```
const Response = fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/auth/loggedIn', requestOption)
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json()
    }).then(json => {return json.loggedIn})
    var loggedIn = await Response
   console.log(loggedIn)
```

The console always reads false and I get redirected to the login page (happens every time the user is seemingly not logged in).

Do you have any idea what I could try to fix the issue? My frontend runs on Next.js, the Backend on Express.js
The RequestOptions passed to fetch() currently is:

```
const requestOption = {
    method: "GET",
    mode: 'cors' as RequestMode,
    credentials: 'include' as RequestCredentials,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
}
```

EDIT:
as requested, here is the rest of the code for my index.tsx-file. The request, as far as I know, is being made from the server-side in getServerSideProps().

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import HeroDash from '../components/hero_dash'
import CookieBanner from '../components/CookieBanner'
import Tutorial from '../components/Tutorial'
import Outset from '../components/Outset'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
    const handleSearchClick = () => {
        setSearchIcon(!searchIcon)
        console.log(searchIcon)
    }
    const [searchIcon, setSearchIcon] = useState(false)
    return (
        <>
            <div className="h-screen bg-cultured dark:bg-raisin">
                <Navbar />
                <HeroDash />
                <div className="columns-2 gap-x-10 px-10">
                    <div className="break-after-column">
                        <Outset />
                    </div>
                    <div className="">
                        <Tutorial />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-center">
                    <CookieBanner hidden={true} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const requestOption = {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include' as RequestCredentials,
    }

const Response = fetch(
    'http://localhost:3001/api/auth/loggedIn',
    requestOption
)
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json()
    })
    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json.loggedIn)
        return json.loggedIn
    })
var loggedIn = await Response
console.log(loggedIn)

if (!true) {
    return {
        redirect: {
            destination: '/login',
            permanent: false,
        },
    }
}

return {
    props: {},
}
```

}

Thank you in advance and have a wonderful weekend

Emily

Comment: What file and/or function is that fetch request being made from? Is it being made from the client-side or server-side? Can you share the remaining code for that file?

Comment: The post has been edited. It now includes the entire index.tsx-file.

Comment: Cookies are not automatically sent when making a request from the server-side (`getServerSideProps`), you have to explicitly pass them. See [Why are cookies not sent to the server via getServerSideProps in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057271/why-are-cookies-not-sent-to-the-server-via-getserversideprops-in-next-js).

Answer (score 0):

The option `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` is unnecessary, because GET requests have no content type. But setting this header causes the browser to precede the GET request with a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request), to which your server probably does not respond as expected.

Please check if omitting this header solves the problem. If not, please check your browser's network trace and the filtered-out request cookies.

Comment: Dear Heiko,

thanks for your response, the header option has been removed, but the server still cant receive the necessary token to validate my login.
Kind regards, Emily

Comment: As far as I can see there are no filtered out request cookies in my trace, neither on the request im trying to sent through requesting '/' or by calling the api directly, both show the cookie in the network trace as non-filtered