# I want to fetch my passport js url endpoint using getServerSideProps in next js

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, session-cookies, getserversideprops

I can fetch and get logged in user data without using serverside props but I can't get the data using getServerSideProps in next js. I think the reason is. it is not sending cookies with get request.

frontend

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Login = () => {
// perfectly working.
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:5000/auth/login/success",
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
      console.log(data.user);
    };
    getUser();
  }, []);

  const google = () => {
    try {
      window.open(`http://localhost:5000/auth/google`, "_self");
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  return <button onClick={google}>Login with Google</button>;
};

export default Login;

// do not work
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:5000/auth/login/success",
      {
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );
    console.log(data);
    return {
      props: {
        user: data.user,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {
        user: false,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

//backend code

```
router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "successfull",
      isLoggedIn: true,
      user: req.user,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Unauthorized: User is not logged in",
    });
  }
});
```

is there any way to include my cookies when sending a get request from server side props?

Comment: You can retrieve the cookies inside `getServerSideProps` from `context.req.headers`.

Comment: how do I include my cookie in the axios request?

Comment: Cookies are set in the request headers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69058105/19405704) SO answer.